# How to rebind event to dynamic created elements in jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, events, plugins, bind

I am creating a plugin and got something problems:

in the case:

I have a list of un-list created by ajax loaded .such as :

```
<ul id='ulist'>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
</ul>
```

then **li were binded** with **hover event** when they loaded. such as :

```
$('ul').bind('hover',function(){});
```

but my plugin **had a function to dynamic adding new li item to the ul[id='ulist'] which had been loaded**.and the new li **didn't get the hover event binding**.Such as:

```
addNewLi : function(){
    $('<li />').html('item N').appendTo('#ulist');
}
```

So,I knew I should bind the new dynamic created elements by **'live'**,but I don't know where to put it or have other way ....

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the twin handler functionality of `hover` in `live` or `delegate`.  That functionality is, I believe, planned for jQuery 1.5.

However, `hover` is actually only a shortcut for the two events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so it's actually very easy to mimic the functionality using these events.

Example using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#ulist').delegate('li', 'mouseenter', function() {
    // code for mouseenter
}).delegate('li', 'mouseleave', function() {
    // code for mouseleave
});
```

Comment: You can use `'hover'` with live/delegate, but you just can't pass it 2 functions. Instead you need to test for the event type. Still +1 on the delegate solution.

Comment: work fine for me!!  Thank you very much! You gave me another way to code my plugin!!